# How can I apply a transformation matrix to a point in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Suppose I have a transformation matrix `Mat` `tr` that I got from `getAffineTransform()` and a `Point2d` `p`. I want the point that is the result of warping `p` with `tr`. Does OpenCV provide a way of doing this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`cv::transform`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transform) is used for transforming points with a transformation matrix.

> Every element of the N -channel array src is interpreted as N -element vector that is transformed using the M x N or M x (N+1) matrix m to M-element vector - the corresponding element of the output array dst .
>   The function may be used for geometrical transformation of N -dimensional points, arbitrary linear color space transformation (such as various kinds of RGB to YUV transforms), shuffling the image channels, and so forth.

There's a concise example in the [`InputArray` documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#inputarray) (otherwise not relevant):

```
std::vector<Point2f> vec;
// points or a circle
for( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
    vec.push_back(Point2f((float)(100 + 30*cos(i*CV_PI*2/5)),
                          (float)(100 - 30*sin(i*CV_PI*2/5))));
cv::transform(vec, vec, cv::Matx23f(0.707, -0.707, 10, 0.707, 0.707, 20));
```

Or you can likely just convert the `Point2f` into a `Mat` and multiply by the matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does exactly what I wanted, I even had a vector already full of points that transforming. Plus theres some other functions that I also wanted in that same documentation page. Super useful.

Comment: I want to add that if you have access to a rotation vector (angle-axis representation), you need to convert it to rotation matrix using `Rodrigues()` function then you can pass it as an argument to `transform()`.